# What is the word when people come up with the same idea independently

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose Darwin and Wallace independently come up with a similar idea. It's like the idea has entered the social consciousness at that time.  What is the word for this called? Kind of the tipping point where everyone catches on and starts doing similar stuff independently.

Okay thanks guys for your answers, I am a huge fan of the site and I've been a long time lurker, this worked out well. :)

Comment: It's quite directly and unimaginatively called "[***Multiple Discovery***](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_discovery)" and is typically contrasted with the "['*Heroic Theory*' of Invention and Discovery](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroic_theory_of_invention_and_scientific_development)".

Comment: Yeah sorry I did know that, I just thought there was a better, more cool name.

Comment: I wish there were too; but I once spent a good bit of time looking for a cooler phrase than "*An idea whose time has come*", and didn't find anything pithier. You might say something was "*In the zeitgeist*", but that has its own flaws.

Comment: Why can't we just make both of those words up right now? What is stopping us? We can be the anti-1984, let's coin these bitches

Comment: Hey, I'm open to it! You have any ideas to start with?

Comment: For your "An idea whose time has come", I was thinking along the lines of 'social conscience saturation point' or something like that, but simpler?

Comment: "Race to the patent office" is used in the context of IP law. See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_to_file_and_first_to_invent

Comment: In history of science, this is known as "Railroad time". I.e, when the economy has reached a certain state of infrastructure (coal, steel, and land available, plus steam engines and demand for transportation), it's "Railroad time", and the idea of building railroads occurs to many people naturally at the same time. As it in fact did. Much the same thing happened a century or so later with the automobile.

Comment: @ben Synchronicity.

Comment: Biologists have this nailed with the concept of __convergent evolution__.

Comment: @JoeDark Yes! That is the word I was looking for. Brilliant, cheers

Answer (score 2):

As @Dan Bron points out in his comment, [multiple discovery](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_discovery) fits the bill perfectly.

Other terms that are sometimes used are **simultaneous invention** or **independent invention**. Frequency of occurrence in Google Search are:

```
    Multiple discovery:     26,600    
    Simultaneous invention: 12,100    
    Independent invention:  69,900
```

In Google books:

```
    Multiple discovery:      4,780
    Simultaneous invention:  4,460
    Independent invention:  33,500
```

See this [Ngram.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=simultaneous%20invention%2Cmultiple%20discovery%2C%20independent%20invention&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csimultaneous%20invention%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmultiple%20discovery%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cindependent%20invention%3B%2Cc0) The figures for independent invention are possibly skewed because this term is used in patent law.

If you're looking for a better, more cool name, [synchronicity](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synchronicity) might work:

> the coincidental occurrence of events and especially psychic events (as **similar thoughts in widely separated persons** or a mental image of an unexpected event before it happens) that seem related but are not explained by conventional mechanisms of causality —used especially in the psychology of C. G. Jung

For added coolness (depending on your age :-)) it's also the title of a [1983 album by The Police.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronicity_%28The_Police_album%29)

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way to describe just this kind of situation is by saying that the idea was **(floating) in the air**. And unlike most other suggestions on this page, this particular metaphor is not limited to English to boot.

Comment: Before you ask: I can vow for German, French, and Russian. That's Germanic, Romance, and Slavic right there, so I wouldn't be surprised to see a whole array of other languages join the choir with their calques. (**Edit:** now also confirmed in our chat for Spanish and Dutch.) Not sure who started it, but I feel like betting an insubstantial amount on Ancient Greek philosophers.

Answer (score 0):

I remember learning about the *concept* you're referring to - as observed in Japanese monkeys learning to wash their food... i.e. the "tipping point" when all the monkeys suddenly started washing - even though they had no contact with the behavior. I think they called it "Hundredth Monkey Syndrome"

Answer (score 0):

Collective consciousness is another way to describe it. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_consciousness

Comment: Apparently your link doesn't show the term *collective consciousness* means a term that is used when people come up with the same idea independently.

Answer (score 0):

[Morphic Resonance by Rupert Sheldrake:] (http://www.sheldrake.org/research/morphic-resonance)

Answer (score -1):

How about **great minds think alike**? 
This proverb seems quite relevant.

Comment: True, however it might not necessarily be a good idea :P

Comment: That should be bad minds think alike ;)

Comment: Hahaha, touche good human

Answer (score -1):

It is known as 'Zeitgeist' when two things of the same nature are thought of or done independently of each other.

Comment: Zeitgeist means spirit of the times, a somewhat different phenomenon.

Comment: My German spouse shares your opinion of the applicability of this word to the Darwin-Wallace scenario.