# Term for the situation in which two people use the same words or original ideas in their works, neither being aware of the other one's work

Tags: single-word-requests

Plagiarism is the process of taking another person’s work, ideas, or words, and using them as if they were your own. But I wonder if there is any particular term for the situation in which two people come up with the same original ideas or use the same original words in their own works, neither being aware of the other one's work.

For example, I'm writing an essay on Bernard Shaw, exploring his plays from a particular perspective, unaware of the fact that someone else has already done the same thing.

Comment: What we call that round here is a [duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/210794/191178) (though that's more science focused, so you might be able to edit to differentiate).

Comment: In US court cases of claimed plagiarism, judges are more willing to accept the likelihood of **parallel creativity** than *Since I can prove I wrote it first, and they could have seen it somehow, they must have stolen it. Thus plagiarism.*

Comment: Simultaneous discovery. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_discovery

Comment: It is not a proper answer but we might say “Great minds think alike”.

Comment: Simultaneous discovery can happen because something is *in the Zeitgeist*, suggesting that it's going to inevitably appear multiple times given the general context and environment. On the other hand, it might be a genuinely freakish coincidence.

Comment: Charles Addams did a superb cartoon involving this. [WordPress__Separated at birth, the Mallifert twins meet accidentally_](https://thewonderoftwins.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/mallifert-twins.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that often enough,  the adverb "*independently" is a term that applies to such situations ; it is found in particular with the verb "to discover"  ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=discovered+independently&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdiscovered%20independently%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdiscovered%20independently%3B%2Cc0), [examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22discovered%20independently%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)).

*Discoveries*

([ref.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz%E2%80%93Newton_calculus_controversy)) The prevailing opinion in the 18th century was against Leibniz (in Britain, not in the German-speaking world). Today the consensus is that Leibniz and Newton *independently* invented and described the calculus in Europe in the 17th century.

*Ideas*

This adverb can also be used to the same effect in a situation of ideas occurring to several persons whithout there being any plagiarism involved.

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Proceedings_Of_The_International_Congres/Gj7ICgAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22occured+independently%22&pg=PA864&printsec=frontcover)) I am sure that the very natural idea to study knots of non-zero thickness occured *independently* to many other mathematicians, yet I found only one paper on “thick” knots preceding

([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=MQwAAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA3&dq=%22occured+independently%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjz5de17P31AhWIyYUKHfazB24Q6AF6BAgdEAI#v=onepage&q=%22occured%20independently%22&f=false)) The Smyth report points out that the same idea occured *independently* to the British physicist Cockcroft, and Turner has told me that von Halban, working in France, had the same idea at the same time.